# Apache stops suddenly with the error "couldn't grab the accept mutex"

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, http

My Apache suddenly stops with this log.

```
[Thu Feb 06 04:46:29.670924 2020] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 5296] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Thu Feb 06 04:46:29.675338 2020] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 6530] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Thu Feb 06 04:46:30.283579 2020] [core:alert] [pid 5291] AH00050: Child 5294 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
[Thu Feb 06 04:46:30.283630 2020] [:emerg] [pid 5291] AH02818: MPM run failed, exiting
```

I started Apache with this command `systemctl apache start` and it works for a while, but after a few hours it suddenly stops.

My server is just a development server, so there is not many access.

What is wrong?

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-09-16T12:58:48
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:68
Server loaded:  APR 1.6.3, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Compiled using: APR 1.6.3, APR-UTIL 1.6.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Comment: Did you Google this error? If so, did you try any of the fixes that are given on other sites?

Comment: Like @SamForbis stated, have you tried to google your error and apply the different solutions? Take a look on this page, seems to be the same error https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000066465-The-Apache-service-is-crashing-AH00144-couldn-t-grab-the-accept-mutex